# Update and shut down in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to force the machine to update when shutting down, instead of going through a reboot? I never leave my machine on and this would be more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Windows 8, Windows uses a logoff + hibernation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8.aspx) as default shutdown. Hold the SHIFT key when clicking on Shutdown. Here Windows uses the old way to shutdown and installs the updates.

Comment: I have update and shut down showing in Windows 8.1 at work, and I don't recall doing anything special to get that to appear. This is no longer the case for 10?

Comment: it should be the same in Win8 and Win10. I don't use Windows 10 so often.

Comment: Win10 no longer seems to display that option but shift works.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the full shutdown (disable fastboot Option) in Windows 10, then it should install Updates on Shutdown.

You have to go to the Control Panel, search for and click on "Power Options", then on the left side click on the link "Choose what the power buttons do", then click on the link "Change settings that are currently unavailable" and then on the lower part of the Windows in "Shutdown settings" disable the Option "Turn on fast startup (recommended)"